# Time Capsule. Drive is ok, cannot connect through wifi

Tags: time-capsule

I am having a problem with my 2TB (I think Gen 2) TC.

It was connected directly to a cable modem and was working fine for over a year. A few days ago, I started to get connection errors (no IP) on both the Ethernet and wifi ports. The wired computers are connected to the TC through a hub.

I changed the connection to link to the net through a spare router, and changed the TC to "Bridge Mode".

All the connected (Ethernet) ports work ok. I have no WiFi mode though (from the TC).

I can see the TC and even do a Time Machine backup to it.

Before I plonk $300 on a new device, I would appreciate any troubleshooting tips..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others who are having this issue, the hardware is ok. The problem is with the current version of firmware - 7.6.1.

I finally found [this site](http://frank.is/mountain-lion-and-the-old-airport-utility/) that allowed me to use Airport Utility 5.6 with Mountain Lion. Using Frank's patch (see the site link above), I was able to roll back the firmware version to 7.6.

To do this, open AU 5.6 and select Manual Setup [image]

Hover over the Version, and you'll see the little arrow.

[image]

Then click Version and select the software version. (7.6 seems ok). Ignore calls to update after this.

[image]

Comment: +1. Was having some issues with Time Machine backing up to the Time Capsule drive on 7.6.1. Used this tip and backups are working fine all around once more. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the latest firmware and have you already tried resetting the TC to factory defaults?

Comment: I do have the latest firmware (7.6.1). I've tried to reset it by unplugging, holding the switch in the back for 5- 10 seconds, but somehow, I'm not sure that really got the device back to factory settings. Is there a more robust method?

Comment: I thought you could reset ir from the GUI itself. Anyway, this should help you out: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3728